# Click and Hover functions to each element in a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a list of elements in an ul, each with its own click and hover function, but for some reason, all list elements get bound the last function I try to bind. I've tried a lot of work arounds, but they all seem to produce the same effect. Here is my code (written with the idea and not the actual variables

```
for ( var i in JSON_object) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    $(li).attr("id","listitem" + i.toSting() );
    $(li).text(JSON_object[i]["name"]);
    $(li).hover(function1, function2);
    $(li).click(function3);
    $("ul").append(li);      
}
```

This correctly displays each list item, including giving each their own text and id. But all the list items get bound the LAST items click and hover function, even if i try to bind the function using the list element's id, i. e.:

```
    $("listitem" + i.toSting()).hover(function1, function2);
    $("listitem" + i.toSting()).click(function3);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The functions are actually much more complex then function1... ect., they actually bind other parts of "JSON_object[i]" to the item. For example, function1 for first list item, will make the item say SON_object[0]["description"], and function2 will go back to  JSON_object[0]["name"].

Comment: The problem is likely in those functions so you will probably need to disclose the code for those for us to help you more specifically.  For example, what does "bind other parts of JSON_object[i]` mean?  I worry about a reference to `i` anywhere in those functions because `i` will no longer have the right value because teh `for` loop has ended.

Comment: @jfriend00
What you have described seems to be the problem, I'm going to use the objects index instead. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have presented.

My guess here is that your `function1()`, `function2()` and `function3()` are not written properly to reference the `this` pointer so that they can discern which element caused the event or those functions are trying to use the variable `i` which they cannot do because the `for` loop will have finished and will contain only the last value for `i`.  If you disclose the code for those functions, we can advise further how to correct them.

I could suggest some simplifications/optimizations of your code using jQuery chaining:

```
for ( var i in JSON_object) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    $(li).attr("id", "listitem" + i)
        .text(JSON_object[i]["name"])
        .hover(function1, function2);
        .click(function3);
        .appendTo("ul");      
}
```

Comment: @user2536917 - what is `lab` and how is it set?  Also, see the edits I applied to my answer about using the `i` variable in any of those functions.

Comment: To put in the varibles as above 
`function() {     $(this).text(JSON_object[i]["description"]);
, function() {
$(this).text("JSON_object[i]["name");
}`

Comment: Im beginng to thing the problem is that since i is changing each loop, its maintaining the last value for i when it executes the function... I'm not sure how to get around this

Comment: @user2536917 - if you show the code that is using `i` in it's context from your other code, I could show you how to get around it using a closure.